# Transpose SQL columns onto rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've loaded an extract of data into a dummy table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ID x Values](
    IDNumber [varchar](50) NULL,
    [3001] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [3013] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [3020] [varchar](50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ID x Values]
           ([IDNumber]
           ,[3001]
           ,[3013]
           ,[3020])
Values('1111', '1', '', ''),
('2222', '', '2', ''),
('3333', '23', '', '4'),
('4444', '1', '', '2')
```

The first column is an item ID. The following columns are locationIDs and inventory levels for some dummy items. I.e. Item ID 1111 has 1 item of inventory at location 3001, 0 units at 3013, and 0 units at 3020.

I'm having some trouble writing a query to transpose these columns into single row records. The result I'm looking for is something like:

```
ItemID   LocationID   InventoryLevel
-------  -----------  ---------------
1111     3001         1
2222     3013         2
3333     3001         23
3333     3020         4
4444     3001         1
4444     3020         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNPIVOT` to get the desired output

```
SELECT
    IDNumber AS ItemID,
    LocationID,
    InventoryLevel
FROM [dbo].[ID x Values]
    UNPIVOT (InventoryLevel FOR LocationID IN ([3001], [3013], [3020])) UNPVT
WHERE LEN(InventoryLevel) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES` to make it.

```
SELECT t1.IDNumber,v.LocationID,v.InventoryLevel
FROM [ID x Values] t1 
CROSS APPLY(
    VALUES(3001,t1.[3001]),(3013,t1.[3013]),(3020,t1.[3020])
) v(LocationID ,InventoryLevel)
where InventoryLevel <> ''
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e1ec4b3ee92b60fcfff5a9cfe271697)